# Convertir Serie a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo lo siguiente, que es del tipo **pandas.core.serie.Series**

```
Tipo_Uno Tipo_Dos
W        A1          0
         A2        -27
X        A1          9
         A2         14
         A3         -9
         A4          9
Y        A1          0
         A2         18
         A3          4
         A4         -3
Z        A1         10
         A2        -12
         A3         17
         A4         -8
Name: Neto, dtype: int64
```

Y necesito transformarlo a lo siguiente, que es del tipo **pandas.core.frame.DataFrame** (excluyendo Tipo_Uno='W')

```
   Tipo_Uno   A1   A2   A3   A4
0         X    9   14   -9    9
1         Y    0   18    4   -3
2         Z   10  -12   17   -8
```

Es posible hacer eso...???

Cómo...???

Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [ask]. Parte importante de la cultura del sitio es que al publicar una pregunta se muestre un esfuerzo por parte del autor al incluir el código que ha intentado o lo que ha investigado ya que en este sitio no hacemos tareas/proyectos. Lectura recomendada: ¿Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Answer (score 1):

Para transformar la serie en un DataFrame con el formato deseado, puedes seguir estos pasos:

```
import pandas as pd

# Aquí tienes la Serie original
serie_original = pd.Series(
    [-27, 0, 9, 14, -9, 9, 0, 18, 4, -3, 10, -12, 17, -8],
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [
            ('W', 'A2'),
            ('W', 'A1'),
            ('X', 'A2'),
            ('X', 'A1'),
            ('X', 'A3'),
            ('X', 'A4'),
            ('Y', 'A3'),
            ('Y', 'A2'),
            ('Y', 'A4'),
            ('Y', 'A1'),
            ('Z', 'A3'),
            ('Z', 'A2'),
            ('Z', 'A4'),
            ('Z', 'A1')
        ],
        names=['Tipo_Uno', 'Tipo_Dos']
    )
)

# Filtra los valores en Tipo_Uno diferentes de 'W'
df_filtrado = serie_original[serie_original.index.get_level_values('Tipo_Uno') != 'W']

# Crea el DataFrame final
df_final = df_filtrado.unstack()

# Restablece el índice
df_final = df_final.reset_index()

print(df_final)
```

El resultado final será:

```
  Tipo_Uno  A1  A2  A3  A4
0        X   9  14  -9   9
1        Y   0  18   4  -3
2        Z  10 -12  17  -8
```

Comment: Buen día, bienvenido(a) a la comunidad, te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y leer la sección [answer]. No todas las preguntas deben ser respondidas si no se apegan a los lineamientos del sitio. A la pregunta le hace falta mostrar lo que se ha intentado hacer.